Does there exist a conjugate prior for regression coefficients in bayesian non-negative least squares?
I'm attempting to perform a non-negative least squares regression using the Bayesian approach.
For the model:
$$y = x^T \beta + \epsilon$$
where $ \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$,
an appropriate choice of conjugate prior for regular (i.e. non-constrained) linear regression is the Normal-inverse-gamma distribution,
$$ p(\beta, \sigma^2) = p(\beta | \sigma^2) p(\sigma^2) $$
where
$$ p(\beta | \sigma^2) = N_p(0, \sigma^2 I_p) $$
$$ p(\sigma^2) = IG(a_0, b_0) $$
(see e.g. https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/02/04/bayesian-linear-regression/)
Clearly here $\beta \in R^p$.
My questions are:

Does there exist an appropriate conjugate prior in which the betas are constrained to be positive, as required by non-negative least squares?
Would, for example, the above prior truncated at 0 over $\beta$ be a conjugate prior?
Failing this, what approaches could I take to make progress on this?

